# How to write a simple Adobe Illustrator script in Java?

Tags: java, adobe

I have a folder contains a couple of hundreds of files  with *.eps format.
I want to perform the following tasks on each file using the Adobe Illustrator 2015.

1- Load each *.eps file from a specified folder.
2- Export that file as PNG with 300dpi resolution in another specified folder.
3- Transform the opened *.eps file to 35% horiziontal and vertical scale and save it in another specified folder.

I know that this could be done using Javascripting. It would be great if anyone can give me a template/sample code to perform the above tasks.

Thank you!

Comment: OP please know that Java is not the same as JavaScript. The title should read `JavaScript` not `Java`. - Also, please post the code of what you have tried already, as we can't write code from scratch for you.

Comment: I have at this point no idea if this question is about javascript, java, batch-files [(which is another programmin language)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info), or none of the above.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Thanks for your comment. I have not tried any code as I don't know how to program in Java or Javascript!

Comment: This can be done using JavaScript (not Java), but we still can't write code for you. I'd go and check if there are any Adobe developer docs.